# Can a zombie despawn with a item held or an Armour piece on their body within the Spawn Chunks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can a zombie despawn if it is holding an item  or has an Armour piece on their body within the spawn chunks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As long as a zombie is holding an item or wearing armor that it picked up, it will not despawn.

This behavior is the same, regardless of whether the zombie is in an unloaded chunk, loaded chunk, or spawn chunk.

Comment: If it naturally spawned with armor, it will despawn

Answer (score 1):

As others posted, an armor piece the zombie picked up (didn't spawn with it naturally) will prevent the zombie from despawning.

Important caveat though: if said armor piece is a helmet, and the zombie is exposed to sunlight, the helmet takes continuous damage and will break after a short time, and the zombie will despawn or burn to death right after that happens. That's why if you want to keep the zombie sun-proof and non-despawning, the optimal item is a carved pumpkin; you can also use player and mob heads, say, the dragon heads from end ships - these items have no durability and as such they don't get damaged by sunlight when worn by undead mobs.

Answer (score 0):

If the zombie naturally spawned with armor, and you did give it that armor, it will despawn. If you gave it armor, or you threw items at it and it picked it up, it won't despawn.

Answer (score -2):

Theoretically, any mob with armor or holding an object within the spawn chunks will never despawn, due to the spawn chunks being in memory at all time.

If you want a zombie to not despawn, you can throw a piece of armor, or any item, and if the zombie is able to pick the item, it will not despawn even if the zombie isn't in the spawnchunks.

You can also give the zombie a name with a namtag, that'll work too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure mobs despawn based on how far they are from the player, not whether they are in the spawn chunks.

Comment: OP asked if a zombie with a piece of armor WITHIN the spawn chunks will despawn. I said no. And that’s a fact. It’s a mechanic the technical players use in their servers to make the full server peaceful by filling the mobcap in the spawnchunks. I don’t know what about my response is wrong

Comment: "Theoretically, any mob within the spawn chunks will never despawn" is clearly not true.

Comment: I edited my answer. I'm sorry if it was not clear, my first language it's not the english.

Comment: The explanation to why the zombie won't despawn is still wrong, as it has nothing to do with being "in memory" or not.

Comment: Yes, it has to do with the memory. The spawn chunks are always loaded, that´s why many people build their farms (I.E. Iron Farm) there, so they will always produce. SO, if a Zombie that is holding an Item or wearing a piece of armor that the player throw, it'll never despawn. Actually, you can check the [Wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Spawn_chunk), Literally the first thing it says it's that the spawn chunks are always loaded in memory

Comment: The explanation to why ---the zombie won't despawn--- has nothing to do with spawning chunks. Entities marked with the Persistent tag will NEVER despawn under any circustance. Your phrase ", due to the spawn chunks being in memory at all time." leaves implicit that spawn chunks are a criteria or consequence for entities being persistent.